# Where is 'avatar_set' User method defined in askbot?

Tags: python, django, askbot

Here's a part of  __init__.py file inside /askbot/models folder:

```
def user_update_avatar_type(self):
"""counts number of custom avatars
and if zero, sets avatar_type to False,
True otherwise. The method is called only if
avatar application is installed.
Saves the object.
"""

if 'avatar' in django_settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
    if self.avatar_set.count() > 0:
        self.avatar_type = 'a'
    else:
        self.avatar_type = _check_gravatar(self.gravatar)
else:
        self.avatar_type = _check_gravatar(self.gravatar)
self.save()
```

As you can see, at some point it calls self.*avatar_set*.count(), which I believe should be a method either native in User's Class from /Django/Contrib/auth or added by a User.add_to_class method like many others in this  __init__.py file

But I can't seem to find where this 'avatar_set' method is defined.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a reverse relationship, which is automatically added by Django when you define a ForeignKey pointing at the model. See [the queries documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward).

Comment: Your answer comes right before posting my own, I had just found out what you explain. thanks!